# How to trigger a click on an element using code such as C# or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, bots

I'm coding a little bot that auto like's a post on a new social network.
So now my problem is that when I'm tring to click on the like button, it doesn't click. I've tried all, C# code, Javascript etc etc.

This is the Html Page Code :

```
<div class="stats_wrapper like_stats_wrapper ">
    <span class="like_button like_stats_span sprite_icon">
    </span>

    <span class="count like_count like_button">
        Like
    </span>
</div>
```

I need to trigger the click event on this element using code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery has some simple functionality to trigger a click, or any other event you so wish:

```
$('.count.like_count.like_button').trigger('click');
```

https://api.jquery.com/trigger/